# Getting Errors in console when using winsock2 header file and lib in c

Tags: c++, c, winsock2

The errors im getting in the console area

```
undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
undefined reference to `__imp_htons'
undefined reference to `__imp_inet_addr'
undefined reference to `__imp_connect'
```

The top of my source file is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
```

Im using gcc to compile this on windows to an exe file.

Comment: gcc does not support `#pragma comment lib`. You should link libraries with compiler command line options: `-lws2_32`.

Comment: Yea that fixed it i had to add the compiler flag and it worked.